# NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays problem

Tags: angular

I faced with `Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays` problem when I try to get static data from service and then iterate with ngFor.Everything seems correct about my data and I dont know why it happens?

**car.service.ts**

```
private cars=[{id:"1234",name:"Honda"},{id:"4322",name:"Mitsubishi"},{id:"532",name:"Jaguar"}]
getCars(){
return this.cars
}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
cars;
getCarsFromService(){
this.cars=this.carService.getCars();
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
  <div (appInvoke)="getCarsFromService();">
    <div class="card-list">
        <a *ngFor="let car of cars" class="card">
      </a> 
    </div> 
  </div>
```

Comment: getCars is defined in service? do you want to invoke getCarsFromService() in template?

Comment: @huanfeng sorry I made typo.I just corrected

Comment: what's the appInvoke attribute mean here?

Comment: Its like a trigger.Runs the function when HTML div rendered

Comment: You don't need to trigger it like this, use an async pipe. If there is an observer, it will automatically trigger the method for you.

Answer (score 0):

In Anuglar, it's better to always to rxjs:

In service, it's better to return an Observable:

```
export class CarService {
  constructor() {}

  private cars = [
    { id: "1234", name: "Honda" },
    { id: "4322", name: "Mitsubishi" },
    { id: "532", name: "Jaguar" }
  ];
  getCars() {
    return of(this.cars);
  }
}
```

In component, adding an observer to it:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private carService: CarService) {}
  cars$;
  ngOnInit() {
    this.cars$ = this.carService.getCars();
  }
}
```

In template, use async pipe:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="cars$ | async as cars">
  <div class="card-list">
        <a *ngFor="let car of cars" class="card">{{car.name}}
      </a> 
    </div> 
</ng-container>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-sua7dd